# Discord.py attachments are not appearing in message return

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

Discord.py version 1.4.1

Hi,
I want to make a log system that will save every message that users delete. This system works fine for normal messages but is struggling when these messages include images or other files (I believe these are called attachments).

The idea is that when a message is deleted my code should check to see if the message contained an attachment, if so it will grab the url and then log it by sending it to a hidden text channel in the server:

```
@bot.event
async def on_message_delete(message):
    if (retrieveSetting("logDeletedMessages") == True):
        for guild in bot.guilds:
            if guild.name == GUILD:
                break

        if (discord.utils.get(bot.get_all_channels(), name="deleted-messages") == None):
            await guild.create_text_channel('deleted-messages')
            deletedMessages = discord.utils.get(bot.get_all_channels(), name="deleted-messages")
            await deletedMessages.set_permissions(guild.default_role, read_messages = False, send_messages = False)

        deletedMessages = discord.utils.get(bot.get_all_channels(), name="deleted-messages")

        try:
            print(message.attachment)
        except:
            print("no attachment")

        avatar = bot.get_user(message.author.id).avatar_url

        embed=discord.Embed(color=0xd400ff)
        embed.set_author(name=message.author.name,icon_url=avatar)
        embed.add_field(name="Message Content:", value=message.content, inline=False)
        embed.add_field(name="Message Location:", value=message.channel.name, inline=True)
        await deletedMessages.send(embed=embed)
```

At the moment all this code doing is, trying to print out what the attachment is but every time I delete a message that contains a picture or a file, `message` never contains the attachment which means I can't display it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's because `message` doesn't have an 'attachment' property. The property you're looking for is 'attachments', which is a list of attachments.

Source: [documentation](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#message)

Comment: That is infuriatingly the fix. Sorry for wasting your time and thank you for the help. All working now :)